# Show "Please wait.." message when expanding TreeView in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a lots of items in my TreeView and items are also very complex. I don't want to use virtualization. Expanding TreeView sometimes takes a lot of time. So therefore, is there any event like: "IsTreeViewExpanding" or something like that where I can show information like "TreeView is being generated...Please wait". How can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WPF's TreeView has no BeforeExpand event, you seem to have to hack into the `OnExpanded()` method on the TreeViewItem, as detailed in [this MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/246c3eb0-2e93-4a45-9ffc-b2e3632b8925).